# Removing chars from expression using regex Python

Tags: python, regex, text

My code is

```
text = 'his eyes she eclip ++ @ #ses and predominates the whole of her sex'
alphabets = set(string.ascii.lowercase)
punctuation = ['!', ',', '.', ':', ';', '?']
allowed_chars = alphbets.union(punctuation, ' ')
regex = re.compile('[^allowed_string]')
text = regex.sub(' ', text)
```

The above code as per my understanding should remove all other characters except lowercase ascii and punctuations marks from any given text.

But when I execute it the result is:

```
is e es s e e li    ses and redo inates t e w ole o  er se
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: can you please show me your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `string.ascii.lowercase` is invalid. i think you meant [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)

Secondly, you can't use a variable with `re.compile` like that. it'll just be a regular string.

Here is a much better solution.

```
>>>import re
>>>text = 'his eyes she eclip ++ @ #ses and predominates the whole of her sex'
>>>re_cmp = re.compile("[^a-z!,.:;?]+")
>>>re_cmp.sub(' ',text)
'his eyes she eclip ses and predominates the whole of her sex.'
```

Comment: No need to escape all these characters within a class, additionally use a quantifier, so that you end up having `re_cmp = re.compile("[^a-z!,.:;?]+")`. This is more readable and effective. +1 though for the regex solution.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Himal  this does the trick, and now I also understand what my code was doing it was replacing all characters except in "allowed_string" string (not variable) by an empty space.